# That's you (that table is for you / is your table)

Tags: grammar, idioms, ellipses

A waitress, who is going to serve a dish to a lady, says "**That's you**" pointing towards an empty table, at which the lady sits.

The scene is from the series Shameless, s07e08, min 5:40

What does "that's you" mean? How productive is that structure?

EDIT:

A similar context can be seen in [this scene, min 5:10](https://youtu.be/bdCyEBdUSTE?t=310)

Comment: How can a table be empty if someone is sitting at it?

Comment: It sounds like a comparison is being drawn. Without additional context, the waitress is indicating that the person she's speaking to was like, is like, or will be like the person who she's pointing to.

Comment: they have to match tables up with names, so just name the table after the person. they will do the same when distributing mail to people or any other matching task.

Comment: "The former" means *the* ***first*** *of two people mentioned*, which in your sentence is the waitress. So are you saying the waitress sat at the table?

Answer (score 2):

Given the context, I think you mean to say "at which the latter sits". It sounds like the waitress is motioning to a table, telling the customer to sit at it so she can serve them.

Assuming that's the case, "that's you" is a slang phrase, shortened and colloquial. The meaning is generally understood by native speakers (I assume the character in the show then sat at the table).

"That's you" has words cut out and shortened. It means something like "That's your table" or "That's where you sit".

We (humans) are lazy in speech, so words are often combined (gonna = going to) or cut out for efficiency in any language and dialect.

Comment: That is the context

Comment: Can any pronoun be used, instead of you?

Comment: @GJC No, because the waitress is talking directly to the customer. When you are directing a question or statement to someone, you use the pronoun "you". (Just as I am referring to you as... well, "you".)

Comment: @Gwendolyn My understanding of the question "can any pronoun be used?" is "can this phrase be used for other conjugations i.e. {me, you he, she, them} etc. 
The answer to this is: yes, but the context must be clear.  An example would be if two people were talking and a car pulled up next to them. One person points to the car and said "that's me". They would mean that this car is here for them. i.e. to pick them up.

Comment: @Colm Ah, yes. You're definitely right. :) I was responding for the given context only, but it makes sense to explain that the phrase can be used in other situations. Thanks!